# How to get alternate name in Facebook?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql

I can't find it in the Graph API, is there some way to get the alternate name someone fills out in their Account Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to access this field via the API by any means i'm aware of, you could file a wishlist item in the [bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs), it may get picked up and implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the user's 'username'? It's a field in the [User Graph Object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). For example, if you want 'btaylor' returned for this user, https://www.facebook.com/btaylor, you'd grab the 'username' field from the User Graph Object, as in this example: https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor.

Comment: No, he means the 'alternate' name field, it's frequently used for users to enter their pre-marriage name, or a celebrity name they're known under (e.g Snoop Dogg's profile: https://www.facebook.com/calvinbroadus - the 'Snoop Dogg' after his real name is the 'alternate name' field )